# textit - undefined control sequence

Tags: amsmath

I got a problem using \textit{}`. The error which occurs is

> "Undefined control sequence".

It occurs in a formula.

```
\texitit{P}_{int} = \int_{V^r} \textbf{\textit{P}}^{i+1} : \dot{\textbf{\textit{F}}}^{i+1} dV^r .
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you do not want to get rid of that typo (for whatever reason), you can put `\newcommand*{\texitit}[1]{\textit{#1}}` in your preamble. But I guess, it was not meant to be an own command but is just a single typo as shown in Justin's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your first P has a `\texitit` rather than `\textit`. Notice the extra `i`?

Comment: woooow... and I was searching for hours...thank you!

Comment: @cag the full tex error message (which you did not show) tells you the line in the file and the point on the line where the undefined command is.